# Creating a function to validate Email ID and return 1 if valid and 0 if invalid

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql, sql-function, sql-server-2019

This is my code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnAppEmailCheck]
    (@email VARCHAR(255))   
    --Returns true if the string is a valid email address.  
RETURNS bit  
AS
BEGIN  
     DECLARE @valid bit  

     IF @email IS NOT NULL   
          SET @email = LOWER(@email)  

     SET @valid = 0  

     IF @email LIKE '[a-z,0-9,_,+,-]%@[a-z,0-9,-]%.[a-z][a-z]%'
        AND LEN(@email) = LEN(dbo.fnAppStripNonEmail(@email))  
        AND @email NOT like '%@%@%' 
        AND CHARINDEX('.@',@email) = 0
        AND PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z]%', @email) <> 0
        AND CHARINDEX('..',@email) = 0  
        AND CHARINDEX(',',@email) = 0              
        AND RIGHT(@email,1) between 'a' AND 'z'  
            SET @valid = 1  

     RETURN @valid  
END
```

My fnAppStripNonEmail function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnAppStripNonEmail]
    (@Temp VarChar(1000))
RETURNS VarChar(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @KeepValues AS varchar(50)
    SET @KeepValues = '%[^a-z,^0-9,@,.,-]%'

    WHILE PATINDEX(@KeepValues, @Temp) > 0
        SET @Temp = STUFF(@Temp, PATINDEX(@KeepValues, @Temp), 1, '')
    
    RETURN @Temp
END
```

In the screenshot, every format works fine as per my requirements but it flags 22@gmail.com as 1. I want my email ID to have at least one alphabet.

[image: Please find the screenshot for reference]

Comment: Can you plase provide a text sample of your input data. It's much easier to use it to try out something by copying the text than an image.

Comment: Why do you assume that `22@gmail.com` is invalid? You can't validate an email address with simple patterns or even with regular expressions.[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression) has some very detailed and complex answers and yet even the best will miss cases. The "simple" answers fail even the simplest tests, like `somename@localhost`, a perfectly valid address

Comment: The results show the function rejects a lot of valid addresses. If you want a half-way decent validation you should use a SQLCLR function able to perform the necessary validation. The article [How to verify that strings are in valid email format)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-verify-that-strings-are-in-valid-email-format) normalizes the input, handles Uniicode (which *is* valid), and then uses a *demo* regular expression to validate the email. The article goes to great lengths to warn that simple pattern matching isn't enough

Comment: You can also check [the regex used](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/EmailAddressAttribute.cs) by the `EmailAddressAttibute`.  It's *very* long

Comment: There's a really good discussion and a 99% solution here: https://regular-expressions.mobi/email.html

Comment: After your `IF @email IS NOT NULL` check, you had **two** `SET ....` statement indented - which leads me to believe you thought these two statements would both be executed only when the `IF` check succeeds - **THAT IS NOT THE CASE!** If you want to execute *more than ONE statement* in a `IF` block, you **MUST** use `BEGIN ....... END` - otherwise, **only** the first statement after the `IF` check is "protected" by that check! Only one ...

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckValidEmail(@EMAIL varchar(100))RETURNS bit as
BEGIN     
  DECLARE @bitEmailVal as Bit
  DECLARE @EmailText varchar(200)

  SET @EmailText=ltrim(rtrim(isnull(@EMAIL,'')))

  SET @bitEmailVal = case when @EmailText = '' then 0
                          when @EmailText like '% %' then 0
                          when @EmailText like ('%["(),:;<>\]%') then 0
                          when substring(@EmailText,charindex('@',@EmailText),len(@EmailText)) like ('%[!#$%&*+/=?^`_{|]%') then 0
                          when (left(@EmailText,1) like ('[-_.+]') or right(@EmailText,1) like ('[-_.+]')) then 0                                                                                    
                          when (@EmailText like '%[%' or @EmailText like '%]%') then 0
                          when @EmailText LIKE '%@%@%' then 0
                          when @EmailText NOT LIKE '_%@_%._%' then 0
                          else 1 
                      end
  RETURN @bitEmailVal
END 
GO
```

Comment: Use above script